# NSTextField with Number Formatter not allowing decimal input

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, interface-builder, nstextfield

I'm trying to make a simple Cocoa application where a number is input into a textfield.  When a number is typed into one textfield the other textfield will automatically update with another number (and vice versa).  The textfield that I've dragged into the window is the "Text Field with Number Formatter" from interface builder.  I have the textfields set as delegate which allows them to automatically update.  However, the formatting does not seem to work.  I can't input decimal numbers.  Please help!!!

Header file here:

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

@interface AppDelegate : NSObject <NSApplicationDelegate> {
    IBOutlet NSTextField *number1;
    IBOutlet NSTextField *number2;
}

@property (assign) IBOutlet NSWindow *window;

@end
```

Implementation file here:

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"

@implementation AppDelegate

@synthesize window = _window;

-(void)controlTextDidChange:(NSNotification *) note {
    NSTextField *changedField = [note object];

    if (changedField == number1) {
        float num1 = [number1 floatValue];
        [number2 setFloatValue: (num1*2.0)];
    }

    if (changedField == number2) {
        float num2 = [number2 floatValue];
        [number1 setFloatValue: (num2/2.0)];
    }
}

@end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bit obscure, but what you are trying to do cannot really work but there is an alternative.

In your code you have:

```
float num1 = [number1 floatValue];
[number2 setFloatValue: (num1*2.0)];
```

The first line requests the *current* value of `number1`. As you have a number formatter attached to `number1` it is called to format the text... and if you've entered, say, `123.` at this point the formatted result is `123`... and your decimal point is vanished. You'll notice you cannot enter commas (thousands separators) either.

So the fundamental problem is that after *every* character is typed your code is forcing it to be a valid number *at that point*.

The alternative is to only do your action when the user has entered a complete number. You can either write code yourself to analyze the input as each character is typed, or you can use the quick and easy method of waiting until the user hits  and responding to the action.

To do the latter change your code to:

```
- (IBAction) textDidChange:(id)sender
{
   if (sender == number1)
   {
      float num1 = [number1 floatValue];
      [number2 setFloatValue: (num1*2.0)];
   }
   else if (sender == number2)
   {
      float num2 = [number2 floatValue];
      [number1 setFloatValue: (num2/2.0)];
   }
}
```

and connect it to the control as the "selector" and remove the "delegate" connection you already have.

This solution is less "dynamic" than what you tried, but it does work. To get the dynamic response back you'll need to write more involved code as stated above.

Comment: So I made the changes you suggested for the less dynamic approach and it does allow me to enter decimal numbers.  Question? - how do I format the textfield so that it will display significant digits such as 45 would display as 45.00

Comment: I would really appreciate it if you could give example code on how I could correctly implement this dynamically.

Comment: @Gavin: You can look at methods like `setMinimumFractionDigits:` on `NSNumberFormatter` (and you get the formatter in use using `NSTextField`'s `formatter` method). You might be tempted to use these methods (and there is one for decimal point display) with the dynamic approach but you'll get very strange behaviour as you'll be altering what the user types as they type and the cursor won't be where they think it is...

Comment: @Gavin: Regarding the second comment, this is something you have to figure out yourself! Consider you have to allow not only "1." as valid input but also maybe "1," - and then wait for 3 more digits... What would you display in the second field if the first had "2,34" in it? I'm sure you can make something work, but the semantics/heuristics are non-trivial.

Comment: Ok, I got the formatting to work. I'll save the dynamic updating for another day.  So one last question - How can I make the textfield highlight everything when I click (single-click not double-click) in the text box?  I know there is a [NSTextField selectText:] method but I'm not sure how to use it in my code.

Comment: @Gavin: Try http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/158969-nstextview-firstresponder-notification.html for one solution.

Comment: Could I use NSValueTransfomer to do a dynamic approach?

Answer (score 1):

I know I'm very late to answer but I just ran into the exact same problem and found a nice workaround. Building upon @CRD's answer.

How I accomplished the problem is:

- Store the formatter
- Wipe the formatter from the textfield
- read the value from the textfield
- Reapply the formatter to the textfield

An example of how I did it is below:

```
-(void)controlTextDidChange:(NSNotification *)obj
{
    if ([obj object])
    {
        NSTextField *field = [obj object];
        NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [field formatter];
        [field setFormatter:nil];
        double data = [field doubleValue];
        [field setFormatter:formatter];
        // ...
        // Do other meaningful stuff now
    }
}
```

Not sure if it's the proper way to do it but it worked well for me.

Answer (score 0):

A bit late to the party, but I just ran into this issue myself, and I think I found a concise solution that maintains dynamic updating, yet avoids the formatter kicking in too early, thus preventing the user from entering fractions:

```
- (void)controlTextDidChange:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    NSTextView *fieldEditor = [aNotification.userInfo valueForKey:@"NSFieldEditor"];
    CGFloat floatValue = fieldEditor.textStorage.string.floatValue;
    // Getting the new value from the field editor avoids the formatter kicking in here.
    // You can now use the value as you wish. Probably something like:
   if (sender == number1)
   {
      [number2 setFloatValue: (floatValue*2.0)];
   }
   else if (sender == number2)
   {
      [number1 setFloatValue: (floatValue/2.0)];
   }
}
```

(I typed this into the browser, so it may not be completely correct, but should be close enough. The essential parts are the first two lines: extract the field editor and extract the new value from it.